# invoking apply with a first argument different to this, in Javascript

Tags: javascript

In the following example I get different results depending on the first argument I send to apply

The code is:

```js
var fruitarray = [];
fruitarray[0] = ['strawberry', 'orange'];
fruitarray[1] = ['lime', 'peach', 'banana'];
fruitarray[2] = ['tangerine', 'apricot'];

var array1= fruitarray.concat.apply([], fruitarray); // in this case array1 is 'tangerine'

var array2= fruitarray.concat.apply('undefined', fruitarray); // in this case array2 is 'banana'

var array3= fruitarray.concat.apply(fruitarray , fruitarray); // in this case array3 is 'lime'

var array4= fruitarray.concat.apply(this, fruitarray); // in this case array3 is 'banana'
```

Why?

**** EDIT: *****

Sorry!!!

This is the code:

```js
var fruitarray = [];
fruitarray[0] = ['strawberry', 'orange'];
fruitarray[1] = ['lime', 'peach', 'banana'];
fruitarray[2] = ['tangerine', 'apricot'];

var array1= fruitarray.concat.apply([], fruitarray); 
console.log(array1[5]); // 'tangerine'

var array2= fruitarray.concat.apply('undefined', fruitarray);
console.log(array2[5]); // 'banana'

var array3= fruitarray.concat.apply(fruitarray , fruitarray);
console.log(array3[5]); // 'lime'

var array4= fruitarray.concat.apply(this, fruitarray);
console.log(array4[5]); // 'banana'
```

I'm using Firebug 2.0.9 to test it (Firefox)

Comment: How do you get the commented results ? I'm getting http://jsfiddle.net/seyenaz/gqrafdot/

Comment: What result had you expected?

Comment: I edited the question. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because different arguments produce different outputs!

The `this` parameter to the array `concat` function is not ignored, but rather signifies the array that is concatenated to. That you have gotten the function from `fruitarray.concat.apply(…` doesn't matter, you could've chosen `Array.prototype.concat.apply(…` or `[].concat.apply(…` as well.

So how do you get those results now?

```
fruitarray.concat.apply([], fruitarray);
// is equivalent to
[].concat(['strawberry', 'orange'], ['lime', 'peach', 'banana'], ['tangerine', 'apricot']);
// and gives for array1
['strawberry', 'orange', 'lime', 'peach', 'banana', 'tangerine', 'apricot']
```

```
fruitarray.concat.apply(fruitarray, fruitarray);
// is equivalent to
fruitarray.concat(['strawberry', 'orange'], ['lime', 'peach', 'banana'], ['tangerine', 'apricot']);
// and gives for array3
[[…], […], […], 'strawberry', 'orange', 'lime', 'peach', 'banana', 'tangerine', 'apricot']
```

Now, what happens if you pass something that is not an array (such as as string or a `Window` object)? The thing is simply wrapped into a singleton array that is concatenated, instead of being spreaded.

```
fruitarray.concat.apply('undefined', fruitarray);
// is equivalent to
['undefined'].concat(['strawberry', 'orange'], ['lime', 'peach', 'banana'], ['tangerine', 'apricot']);
// and gives for array2
['undefined', 'strawberry', 'orange', 'lime', 'peach', 'banana', 'tangerine', 'apricot']
```

```
fruitarray.concat.apply(this, fruitarray);
// is equivalent to
[this].concat(['strawberry', 'orange'], ['lime', 'peach', 'banana'], ['tangerine', 'apricot']);
// and gives for array4
[{window}, 'strawberry', 'orange', 'lime', 'peach', 'banana', 'tangerine', 'apricot']
```